# Node.js Express - how to combine file creation and sendFile

Tags: node.js, file, express, response

I know that we can create a new file in nodeJs like this:

```
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(name);
writeStream.write("f1,f2,f3");
writeStream.write("1,2,3");
writeStream.end();
```

and that if we have an absolute path of a file - we can send it as a response back:

```
res.sendFile(name);
```

But how do we combine this, like if I get a post request to create a report, I do some query, put the result into a csv file and then send back the same newly created file?

Update: I see that sendFile is working perfectly - but response is going as text - My question more is - how to trigger a csv download from an ajax request - not a form submit. Is it possible - cause it seems like a huge security risk

Comment: You could get the file after writing it, then send it as a response to the user.

Comment: so should i use a promise??

Comment: If you don't need that file on the server, don't create it on the server. Send the data to the client without writing it to disk first. Promises have nothing to do with any of that. Use a proper module https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv for CSV data.

Comment: I want to create it. how do i create it and send it

Comment: i want to send a csv file download

Comment: Have you tried *searching* for a solution? How many other answers have you read? What did you not understand about them?

Comment: im not able to detect a createWriteStream end event - like this doesnt work:

Comment: let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(name);
 writeStream.on('end', () => {
  
  res.sendFile(name);
 })

Answer (score 0):

suppose `myData` contain your final data ;

```
// This will force download at browser side 
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/force-download','Content-disposition':`attachme‌​nt; filename=myData.csv`});
```

res.end(myData);

```
// you can save your data to file in background

fs.writeFile('sample.csv', myData, function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
});
```

Comment: it may be failed if the file is too big. stream it instead.

Comment: this doesn't work. The server fails saying the headers contain invalid characters